# Use poetry shell in Vimspector

Tags: python, environment-variables, plugin-vimspector

I'm using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to manage my virtual environments for Python and I'm using [Vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector) as a debugger plugin for Vim.

How can I use the Poetry venv when starting debugging?

I'm thinking that all that has to be done is to run the command `poetry shell` on the terminal session that the Vimspector will use, but I haven't out how to do this.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that trying to find an answer, creating a specific adapter is not the best approach.

I asked at [Gitter](https://gitter.im/vimspector/Lobby) of Vimspector and the best way is to specify the path of Python executable, which can be found using `which python` when inside Poetry.

That is, at the configuration (and not at the adapter part) one has to specify:

```
'python': 'path/to/python/inside/poetry`
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create your own adapter in your vimspector configuration.

You can find help in [this documentation](https://puremourning.github.io/vimspector/configuration.html).

Here a configuration I use to run vimspector with poetry and debugpy:

```
{
  "adapters": {
    "poetry-debugpy": {
      "port": "5678",
      "host": "localhost",
      "launch": {
        "remote": {
          "host": "localhost",
          "runCommand": [
            "poetry", "run",
            "python3", "-m", "debugpy",
            "--listen", "0.0.0.0:5678",
            "--wait-for-client",
            "%CMD%"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "python debug": {
      "adapter": "poetry-debugpy",
      "breakpoints": {
        "exception": {
          "all": "Y",
          "uncaught": "Y"
        }
      },
      "configuration": {
        "name": "Python: Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!